# What is the name for this bar chart visualization where successive bars drill down one segment of the previous bar

Tags: data-visualization, barplot

There is a kind of (pretty simple) visualization we use a lot in my office, but none of us knows what it's called:

[image]

The idea is that the second bar drills down into the indicated data from the first bar.  As pictured here, 69% of the first bar is highlighted.  The second bar shows that 76% of that initial 69% is highlighted, and so on.

We usually call these "engagement funnels", but searching online for that term pulls up a very different visualization.  I'm asking because I'd like to build a tool to auto-generate them (likely with a library like d3) but want to know if others are already doing that...

Is there a standard name for this type of display?

(Bonus: do you know of a library or plugin that generates them already?)

Comment: Welcome to our site! I have tried to give a more meaningful title (bearing in mind most people who see the title will do so in a link, so can't see the actual picture), but feel free to edit to change it if you don't like it.

Comment: Never seen it before personally. Do you know **any references at all**, literature or internet? If not, then your name is as good as any other. Nested bar chart???

Comment: @NickCox I know I've seen them in the wild before, but can't think of or find examples off hand.  I'll try to look for something...

Comment: I have certainly seen this before too, though irritatingly I can't recall where.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this called "exploded bar charts". Seems to be mostly an Excel thing, but here's a [Python matplotlib example](http://www.benjaminmgross.com/exploding-bar-chart-for-pythons-matplotlib/). Usually there are just two levels (the normal bar on the left and the exploded bar on the right), so there may be a better name for this cascading version.

Somewhat related and supporting Nick Cox's "nested bar chart" name is the "[nested area graph](http://stephanieevergreen.com/nested-area-graph/)".